# Use SUM and Average both on the same column in Group By statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I have a table as shown in this screenshot:

[image]

I want to group by the Employees to calculate `AssetEarned`, but with the following logic:

1. Sum the same dates, then
2. Average the different dates

The output expected is like the following picture.

[image]

Can this be achieved using a `group by`? I can use `SUM`, or `AVG` in the `group by` statement individually, but not at the same time. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using simple the `SUM` and `Count` functions in SQL

```
SELECT ID,NAME,(SUM(ASSET_EARNED)/CAST(COUNT(DISTINCT DATE) AS FLOAT)) AS ASSET_EARNED 
FROM (
VALUES (1,1,'Bruce',5,'10-Jan'),(2,1,'Bruce',7,'10-Jan'),(3,1,'Bruce',6,'12-Jan'),
       (4,2,'Clark',4,'11-Jan'),(5,2,'Clark',3,'12-Jan')
)S(KeyID,ID,NAME,ASSET_EARNED,DATE)
GROUP BY ID,NAME
```

Another option to avoid the `DISTINCT` inside `Count` function

```
SELECT A.ID,A.NAME,SUM(A.ASSET_EARNED)/CAST(COUNT(DATE) AS FLOAT) AS ASSET_EARNED 
FROM(
SELECT ID,NAME,DATE,(SUM(ASSET_EARNED)) AS ASSET_EARNED 
FROM (
VALUES (1,1,'Bruce',5,'10-Jan'),(2,1,'Bruce',7,'10-Jan'),(3,1,'Bruce',6,'12-Jan'),
       (4,2,'Clark',4,'11-Jan'),(5,2,'Clark',3,'12-Jan')
)S(KeyID,ID,NAME,ASSET_EARNED,DATE)
GROUP BY ID,NAME,DATE) A
GROUP BY ID,NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a subquery in which you `SUM` the values first before using `AVG`:

```
SELECT t.EmployeeID,
    t.EmployeeName,
    AVG(t.AssetEarned) AssetEarned
FROM
(
    SELECT t.EmployeeID,
        t.EmployeeName,
        SUM(CONVERT(FLOAT, t.AssetEarned)) AssetEarned
    FROM yourTable t
    GROUP BY t.EmployeeID, t.EmployeeName, t.[Date]
) t
GROUP BY t.EmployeeID, t.EmployeeName
ORDER BY t.EmployeeID
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use `Count of Unique Dates` and divide sum of asset into them.

```
  SELECT 
    e.EmployeeId,e.EmployeeName,cast(SUM(e.AssetEarned) AS FLOAT)/Cast(COUNT(DISTINCT e.Date) AS FLOAT) AssetEarned
    FROM Employee AS e
    GROUP BY e.EmployeeId,e.EmployeeName
```